# Detecting Whether Key is Being Held Down in Java

Tags: java

I'm implementing a KeyListener, and trying to find out whether a key is being held down in Java, as opposed to just being pressed and released. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: It's held down in between a `keyPressed` and a `keyReleased`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For your implementation of [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html)...

The `keyPressed` method is called when the key is depressed, and the `keyReleased` method is called when the key is released, and this works for almost any key (including CTRL or CMD; generally keys like 'fn' on laptops can't be detected but that's about it).

The `keyTyped` method shouldn't be used if you want this level of fine-tuning; keyTyped is fired when a key is pressed AND released, and will also repeat if the key is held down depending on OS. So don't use that one.